# Location for macdeployqt source

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, macdeployqt

I have to edit my `shared.cpp` file due to some library linking problem but I can't find the location where it is in my Qt folder that I have installed.

The code can be found in here: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qttools.git/tree/src/macdeployqt/shared/shared.cpp

So I need to find qttols where it is so that I can modify `shared.cpp` but couldn't find it.

So in my mac system where can I actually find this `cpp` file?

Edit: I am actually looking for the source of `macdeployqt` to modify.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qttools.git includes the Source of macdeployqt.

So, you can clone the GIT repo, if you don't have Qt source installed on your system.

If you already have the Qt source installed, have a look into:

./qt5/qttools/src/macdeployqt/